# Is it possible to map from a specific element of a list to self?

Tags: java, mapstruct

Given the following classes:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private List<Role> roles;

    public String getRoleByType(String type){
        for(Role role : roles){
            if(type.equals(role.getType())){
                return role;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public interface Role {
    public String getType();
}

public class Driver extends Role {
    private String driverLicenseNr;

    public String getType(){
        return "Driver";
    }
}

public class Professional extends Role {
    private String occupation;

    public String getType(){
        return "Professional";
    }
}

public class DriverDTO {
    private String name;
    private String driverLicenseNr;
}
```

what I'm trying to accomplish is to map Person to DriverDTO.

I was trying something like this:

```
@Mapper
public abstract class DriverMapper {
    
    @Mapping(target = ".", expression = "java(driver.getRoleByType(\"Driver\"))")
    public abstract DriverDTO convert(Person person);

    public abstract void driverToDriverDTO(Driver driver, @MappingTarget DriverDTO driverDto);
}
```

but the annotation processor can't simply generate the code with this. Throws a nullPointerException.
If I do instead (some programming details hidden for simplification):

```
@Mapper
public abstract class DriverMapper {
    
    @Mapping(target = "driverLicenseNr", expression = "java(driver.getRoleByType(\"Driver\").getDriverLicenseNr())")
    public abstract DriverDTO convert(Person person);
}
```

It works, but I want to take advantage of the automated mapping, which in this case I wouldn't. It seems that `target="."` only works with simple mappings using a single object in the source. Is this true or am choosing the wrong path to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using expression MapStruct does not do any evaluation and uses what is in the generated code.

What I would suggest you is to do something like:

```
@Mapper
public abstract class DriverMapper {
    
    public DriverDTO convert(Person person) {
        if (person == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Role role = person.getRoleByType("Driver");

        Driver driver = role instanceof Driver ? (Driver) role : null;

        return convert(person, driver);
    }

    @Mapping(target = ".", source = "driver")
    protected abstract DriverDTO convert(Person person, Driver driver);

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't I be loosing the the person attributes mapping in that case? In this example there's only "name", but my real life scenario has a lot of them..

Comment: How are you going to lose them? The new `convert` method will map from `Person` and `Driver` to `DriverDTO`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Filip, unfortunately I had to put this on hold for a while. Now that I got back to it, I realized that I oversimplified the issue here. In any case you led me on the right direction and I was able to overcome my issue. Thanks again